# String buffer repeats values when used in a loop, Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor, stringbuffer

I am using a string buffer to read to store values being read from an SQLite database. Inside the loop, the buffer always starts reading from the first database reference.

Eg: The database has the values apple,orange,banana.

Everytime I call the funtion,the string buffer stores the items from the beginning:

first function call: apple

second function call: apple apple orange

third function call: apple apple orange apple orange banana

On the third call i need it just to be: apple orange banana

How can I do this?

```
public void db{

Cursor res= databaseHelper.getAllData();
if(res!=null){
    res.moveToFirst();
    try{
    while(res.moveToNext())
    {
        if(res.getString(0)!=null){
        stringBuffer.append(res.getString(0)+"\n");
        Log.i("TAG",stringBuffer.toString());
        stringBuffer1.append(res.getString(1)+"\n");
        stringBuffer2.append(res.getString(2)+"\n");

        stringBuffer.setLength(0);
        stringBuffer1.setLength(0);
        stringBuffer2.setLength(0);

    }catch(Exception e){}}}
```

Comment: Is there are something which is helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Just put `StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");` after `public void db{`  
or clear the `stringBuffer` by `stringBuffer.delete(0, stringBuffer.length());` before you start the loop. 
I don't know where you declared stringBuffer but it keeps the previous values. 
 Also you may lose the 1st item in db because you do `moveFirst` and immediately `moveNext`, so drop `moveFirst`

Answer (score 0):

```
int i =0; 
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){ 
do{
 stringBuffer.append.(cursor.getString (i)); 
i++; 
}
while(cursor.moveToNext());
 }
 cursor.close(); 
}
```

Try this instead of that, may this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just print `"apple orange banana"`, then use as follow

```
public void db(){
    Cursor res = databaseHelper.getAllData();
    if (res != null) {
        while (res.moveToNext()) {
            String value = res.getString(0) + " ";
            stringBuffer.append(value);
            Log.d(TAG, stringBuffer.toString())
            ...
        }
        res.close()
    }
}
```